# PyCharm: option to warn user on typing mismatches

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I would like PyCharm to warn me on the following python3 code:

```
def foo() -> str:
    return 'abc'

x: int = foo()  # I want to be warned here
```

Is there an option I can enable to get this warning?

The motivation here is that I have functions whose return-types are not as easily deducible at first glance like in this example. I want to declare what I *think* the types of my variables should be, for readability, and I want PyCharm to deduce whether what I think is correct.

Comment: mypy will check the types match before running.

Comment: How about syntax highlighting?

Comment: Pycharm *should*, in some way, already inform you that this violates the type annotation.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Are you saying that Pycharm should change their highlighting logic, or that my instance of Pycharm is not behaving as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is an open issue in PyCharm ([PY-24832](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24832)).